# DMS grid when SRC is not in decimal degrees using QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

I have a QGIS project where the layers are in projected SRC, and when I go to the print composer to draw the grid, the units are in millons of meters, and I want them in decimal degrees.

Is it possible to draw the grid´s coordinates in DMS or DD without reproject the layers of the project?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using version 2.6 you can use a grid in a different CRS from the layers and project. You can even have more than one grid.  The only thing for if you want a graticule is to set the X and Y spacing in decimal format.

[image]

As you can see in the image I set the X and Y spacing to show lines every 15 minutes. Also you can see in the image that you can add more than one grid and set their characteristics individually. This is a really useful feature of version 2.6. Previous versions do not have this capability

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.
I just had to upgrade QGIS from 2.4 to 2.6 Thanks again